# Display file text one page at a time, wait 20 seconds, then auto-advance

Tags: text-processing, aix, scrolling, more

This question is for AIX 7

I have been working on a monitor which will display several pages of text.  Initially the end user wanted a scrolling list for which I constructed this:

```
IFS=''; cat plfeed | while read line; do echo $line; perl -e 'select(undef,undef,undef,.8)'; done
```

The end user has decided that they would rather display a page (24 lines) of output for a set amount of time (20 seconds for example).  I know that more will let me display a page at a time, but it requires keyboard input which is not acceptable for my use-case.

tldr;

How can I automate the 'more' command, or build a similar function that will sleep between pages and then automatically advance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fairly standard `awk` should be ok on AIX

```
awk '{if(NR>1 && NR%24==1)system("sleep 20");print}'
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to exit on interrupt, you can replace the `system()` by

```
{if(system("sleep 20"))exit}
```

but it might not work on your OS.

Comment: Nice +1. You could make it a bit shorter: `awk '!(NR%24) { system("sleep 20") } 1'`. This is still very portable.

Comment: You could add a check of the `system()` return value. If it is non-zero, exit, allowing the user to quit with `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-\\`.

Comment: @Thor I didn't want the first page to be exceptionally 23 lines only, hence the test against 1. And I tried testing the return code from `system()` on interrupt but it was always 0 on my fedora! ... Tried on a debian and it worked correctly. Bizarre.

Comment: I see. With regards to the return value, I was testing it with `nawk` where it sort of works. I see the same strange issue with zero return value with GNU awk. `mawk` on the other hand intercepts the signal and quits. So not a very portable solution.

Comment: Thanks -- that made it even more perfecter:

`IFS=''; cat filename | awk '{if(NR>1 && NR%24==1){if(system("sleep 20"))exit};print}'`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect 
set timeout 20
spawn -noecho man autoexpect
while 1 {
  expect {
    timeout { send " " }
    -ex "(END)" { exit }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.

Is there a way to format that as a single line command?

Comment: That should be `#! /usr/bin/expect -f` or `--` instead of `-f`.  Please don't spread the `#! /usr/bin/env` disease any further.  It's bad enough that it's almost universal in the python sphere...python users might not care about arbitrary breakage of the `#!` line (e.g. so that the interpreter can't take args, amongst several other problems) but users of other languages still do.

Comment: I will continue to use `env` as figuring out which `expect` to use on which platform would be needlessly complicated (it's not `/usr/bin/expect` on either of my primary operating systems). I do agree about the python disease part, though.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the nature OP's question using a similar `awk` solution as [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283736/110050).
I've made the following changes:

1. Exit via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
2. Use `$LINES` to get height of terminal.
3. Works on Linux and Mac OSX.
4. Added documentation and explanations.

```bsh
awk -v x=$LINES 'NR % x == 0 && system("sleep 20"){exit} 1'
#    ^^^^^^^^^^  ^  ^^^^^^^^      ^                      ^
#       |        |  |             |                      |
#       |        |  |             |                      |
#       |        |  |             |                      +
#       |        |  |             |   f) pattern-action block which
#       |        |  |             |      prints the current line.
#       |        |  |             |        - Pattern is Truethy.
#       |        |  |             |        - Action is empty
#       |        |  |             |          defaulting to `{print}`
#       |        |  |             |
#       |        |  |             +
#       |        |  |   d) `system` function returns exit code `0` when
#       |        |  |       successful and non-zero on 'ctrl-c'.
#       |        |  |
#       |        |  |   e) `0` evaluates to false, so `exit` will not
#       |        |  |       execute until `ctrl-c` is triggered.
#       |        |  +
#       |        | c) When line number is evenly divisible
#       |        |    by x (the terminal height)
#       |        |    sleep for 1 second.
#       |        | 
#       |        | 
#       |        +
#       |   b) NR current line number.
#       |
#       +
# a) Set variable `x` to Bash variable $LINES.
#    $LINES is set to height of current terminal.
```